# PHP under construction redirect error(closed)

Tags: php

I have a problem with my under construction code with PHP.
This is my code:
PHP: (init.php)

```
$date = new DateTime();
if ($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') < $row['ending']) {
construct();
}
```

The construct(); function: (general.php)

```
$current_file = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$current_file = end($current_file);

function construct() {
$allow = array("MY IP");
if (!in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow)) {
header ("Location: construct");
}
}
```

And the error i have is that it dosen't redirect it. Please help, Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your `construct()` function is being called? Is the condition verified in the first part of your code?

Comment: what that even means? "construct" doesn't look like a correct address :|

Comment: I want to call it when the timestamp i've added in my database is higher than the current date/time and I have edited it in the .htaccess

Comment: you couldn't be doing date comparisons with strings. While a ymdhis format WILL generally work, it's still a bad idea. Have you confirmed that your construct function is actually being called? What's the value of `$row['ending']` at that point?

Comment: The value of $row['ending'] is varchar(2013-11-12 19:00:00)

Comment: Do you output anything before calling header()? If so, this causes the error! Also, you should always call exit() after redirecting with header().

Comment: The code below, by Francisco Presencia worked like a charm! Thanks annyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging it by doing:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$curdate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if ($curdate < $row['ending']) {
  construct();
  }
else {
  echo "Not redirecting properly. Start: " . $curdate . " end: " . $row['ending'];
  // If you are using exceptions to handle errors (as you should),
  // change the line of code above for:
  // throw new Exception("Not redirecting properly. Start: " . $curdate . " end: " . $row['ending']);
  }
```